Does the phrase "no smoke without fire" imply that with fire, there would be smoke?
People use "no smoke without fire" to argue that the metaphorical smoke must be caused by some metaphorical fire.

If there is fire, there would be smoke
If there is smoke, there would be fire

Which (if any) of the above does the phrase imply, and would that implication be free of fallacy?

The phrase usually refers to 2. And the phrase is usually “where there is smoke, there is fire”

"No smoke without fire" is no fire → no smoke, which is the contrapositive of 2, hence equivalent to it in classical logic.

I feel like this expression was coined before people knew as much about fire.  Smoke is mainly just the result of incomplete combustion, so it's actually a failure for fire to actually occur properly.  (You can actually burn smoke under the right conditions to complete the combustion process!) Since incomplete combustion often occurs early in the process of an actual fire, people made an association which is not entirely accurate.  So from a physics perspective, neither implies the other. (Yes, wrong stack i know...)


You k'n hide de fier, but w'at you gwine do wid de smoke?
(Br'er Rabbit proverb)


This isn't a philosophy question, it belongs on English Usage SE.

@MichaelHall What is a 'philosophy question'? Almost every question on this site has a secondary topic... some relate to science, some sociology, some morality. Your comment is about as useless as discussing the sound of one hand clapping.

"...the sound of one hand clapping." Hey, now there's the basis for a new "philosophy" question!  ;) Seriously though, you simply asked for the meaning of a common phrase, and I suggested a better place to ask.  Don't take it so personally.

By that statement (which is, of course, and oversimplification but we're just concerned with logic right now), with no smoke there may still be fire. In more formal detail:
Per the usual mathematical logic "A implies B" evaluates to true if a and b are both true, or a is false (!A | B). That's equivalent to !(A & !B); you can draw the truth tables of both to prove that to yourself.

Smoke implies fire
Either there is no smoke  or there is fire.
You can't have smoke without fire.

That doesn't forbid a smokeless fire.

Jon: true, it produces steam. Good real world counter example.

For extra excitement you also can't see the flame (you need a UV sensor). This is how one gets pure water for semiconductor processing (aka wet oxidation).

This mistake is one of the best-known logical fallacies, called "affirming the consequent". One reason why it is made often is that in the messy real world, "pure" logical conditions (where no conclusions about the atecedent can be drawn from the consequence) are rare. Much more often, real-world relations are general correlations. Most fires do emit (some) smoke. They typically go together.

@JonCuster, did you mean an IR sensor?  I don't know of any combustion processes that create UV.

No, I mean uv. Consider energy levels in an excited hydrogen atom and what it can emit.

This is part of the basics of propositional logic. Both this are OK:

Ponendo Ponens (antecedent produces consequent):fire -> smoke(if there is fire, there will be smoke).
Tollendo Tollens (negation of consequent implies negation of antecedent):NO(smoke) -> NO(fire)(if there is no smoke, there is no fire).

The case "If there is smoke, there would be fire" is fallacious (affirming the consequent).
Many cases of affirming the consequent seem valid (not fallacious), while they are not. That's why, a proper example helps understanding better. For example, if heat can be produced by fire or a heater: fire -> heat (modus ponens: it is sure that fire produces heat); no heat -> no fire (modus tollens, given that it is sure that fire produces heat, and there is not heat, then, there is no fire); heat -> fire (fallacious, affirming the consequent: heat does not imply fire, perhaps it is generated by an electric heater, so, heat -> fire IS FALSE).

Just to be clear: where you say both are OK, they are logically equivalent, which is not to say that they are correct statements about smoke and fire (and they are not.) +1 for bringing up the fallacy of affirming the consequent.

You can have fire without smoke. Many fire sources (e.g. propane, gas stoves, blow torches) don't produce smoke, and there are also devices that suck up the smoke (smokeless fire pits).
But the only cause of smoke (according to this simple proverb) is fire. So if you see smoke, you can conclude that there is a fire causing it.

Simple example of fire without smoke: Any well-mixed propane flame. Be it gas stove, blow torch or bunsen burner. Once you have a translucent blue flame, there won't be smoke.

Thanks, I updated my answer with those examples.

“Seeing smoke implies fire” is used by Indian philosophers since the days of Nyaya, see Nyaya, Anumāna.
The slogan illustrates the method to derive knowledge from logical deduction. In short:

Seeinge smoke implies existence of fire.

The method is recommended in situations where one is not an eyewitness of an event.
